# Basic question about 4-way set associative

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-hardware

When the CPU writes or reads from the memory and stores the value that was read or written into L1 cache. Do the CPU store the whole block( 1 block , leaves the other three ways empty) or the whole set ( 4 blocks)?

Comment: What have tou tried? Where did you get stuck? What have you read? Since it is "basic question" maybe there is "easy to find common reference"?

Comment: Yeah I was wondering how a set associative cache work. Some say that you can write to individual blocks ( one block = 1 way ) and skip the rest. (meaning leaving block(way 2) = empty, block (way 3) = empty , block ( way 4)  four empty and write to block (way 1) = data) or do the CPU write to all the ways immediatly in parallell  (way 1)block 1 = data,(way 2) block 2 = data , (way 3)block 3 = data ,(way 4) block 4= data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four way set associative does not mean 4 sets.

It means each set is of 4 blocks.

Individual block can be read or written.

Go through [this document](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Memory/set.html) for understanding the concept of set associative cache.

Comment: But how do we know if individual blocks are written or all the ways ( 4 blocks each way contains 1 block) are written ? Isnt there a common rule to write to the cache or is it the hardware that decides this rule ????

Comment: Block is collection of bytes.whenever we fetch data into cache from memory the unit of transfer is a block.

Comment: Ok that was the answer I was looking for thanks!